# Custom element not found

Tags: dart, polymer, custom-element

I'm trying to create a custom element, I had several warnings in my result page that I've fixed. The last one is:
`custom element with name "paper-fab-menu" not found. See http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_11 for details.`

I checked the element's code, removed all scripts to make things simple, here's the code

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/paper_elements/paper_fab.html">

<polymer_element name="paper-fab-menu" noscript>

  <template>
    <paper-fab icon='menu'></paper-fab>
  </template>

  <!--<script type="application/dart" src="paper_fab_menu.dart"></script>-->

</polymer_element>
```

There's no warnings about this code.

There's no warning in my index.html code when I import my element (there was one about the incorrect path, but it was solved), here's the import part of my index.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_item.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_submenu.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../lib/custom_paper_elements/paper_fab_menu.html">

<!--<script async type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>-->
<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

The dart editor is still marking the `<paper-fab-menu>` as a warning. Polymer's error states that this error points an incorrect import, but all the imports are solved correctly, I can't see the problem!

Windows 8.1
Dart Editor 1.8.5
Dart SDK 1.8.5

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked if the file it complaints about actually exists? You can try `pub cache repair` on the ccommand line.

Comment: The file exists.
I tried renaming the element name to paperfabmenu (without dashes), and it worked.
Dashes back = problem back
I didn't hear of constraint names in polymer about dashes usage

Comment: The constraint is, that each Polymer element (or each custom element) must have a dash in it's name even when it seems weird in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<polymer_element ...` should be `<polymer-element ...` (dash instead of underline)

You should not go outside the top-level directories using `../`. Only import from `lib` or from within the current top-level directory.
To import from `lib` use `<link rel="import" href="packages/yourpackagename/custom_paper_elements/paper_fab_menu.html">`

For more details see:
https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/app-directories.html
This looks a bit complicated but usually you get good warnings with hints how the import path should look like.

Comment: I added another hint which might cause you troubles.

Comment: The import is another question. I didn't mean to nest directories, but in packages the library name is not created directly under the "packages" folder, it was created under "packages/<Project Name>/custom_paper_elements", that's why I went that weird way to reach the paper_elements package I had to go folder up twice

Comment: The `packages/<ProjectName>` *is* the `lib` folder. You should only import from `lib` this is the reason only `lib` is exposed through `packages`. If you are in `web` you don't need `..` to reach `packages` (sorry for the confusion, I'll fix my answer).